# Read line until int is met java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

If i have the following input:

```
sometext 23,1 -54.2 42
sometext 42,6 32 -56
```

How do i read firstly only the string and then the numbers.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < numLines ; i++){
    name = scanner.nextLine() // Here i want to save "sometext"
    for(int j = 0 ; j < numNumbers ; j++){
        numbers.add(scanner.nextFloat());
    }
    cities.add(new City(name, numbers));
    numbers.clear();
}
```

Comment: In your case: Would it be possible to use `scanner.next` instead of `scanner.nextLine()`? This would only work if 'sometext' is not delimited by any whitespace

Comment: Well, you could have a look at `hasNext(pattern)` and pass a regex that matches words only. But you could also try to just read the entire line and parse it, e.g. by splitting it at spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, don't ever call `nextLine`. It doesn't do what you think it does, and what it does do, is almost entirely useless. Yes, it shows up in every tutorial under the sun.<sup>1</sup>

Just call `.next()` if you want a string.

Thus, here, you should be invoking `next()` to read strings, and `nextDouble` to read doubles. Except you have **utterly bizarre** input, where sometimes commas show up and sometimes dots, to separate inputs. Did you make a typo when copying this over? If this is indeed your input, you can only use `next()`, and then you ahve to massage this broken crazy input first before turning it into numbers.

Also, you don't ever want to use `float` either. Just use double<sup>2</sup>. For everything. No it is not 'less efficient' or 'takes more memory'. It's just better, for free.

### That was a typo, the input is consistent.

Ensure the scanner has the proper locale set, otherwise it will be expecting a `,` as separator instead of a `.` or vice versa. Failure to set locale means that your app will randomly not work depending on the configuration of the host system you're on, you usually do not want that. Use `scanner.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)` for example to do this.

Then:

```
name = scanner.next(); // returns "sometext"
for (int j = 0; j < numNumbers; j++) {
    numbers.add(scanner.nextDouble());
}
```

### It really is that mixed crazy

Then instead of `.nextDouble`:

```
String raw = scanner.next();
raw = raw.replace(",", ".");
numbers.add(Double.parseDouble(raw));
```

### You also have a bug

Java is pass-by-value, but `numbers` **is a reference**. It's like me handing you, on a note, an _*address* to a building, and then me driving over there and burning the place to cinders. It doesn't matter that the address I gave you was written on a copied piece of paper you drove off with. If you follow your personal copy of that address, you still find a burnt out house.

So, when you write `numbers.clear()`, you're removing the numbers from that newly created city. What you want instead of `numbers.clear()`, which is java-ese for: "Take the piece of paper that you named `numbers`, which has an address written on it. Drive over there. Burn the house down.", and replace it with: `numbers = new ArrayList<Double>()` which is java-ese for: "Build a new house on a free spit of land. Take your piece of paper called `numbers`, and erase whatever is written on there. Now jot down the address to this newly built house.".

You want the second thing. Remember, `.` is java-ese for: Drive to the address written on here, and `=` is: Mess with the address itself, do not drive anywhere.

1] You don't need to follow this reasoning to use Scanner, but for those who'd like to know why I say this: Mixing nextLine and nextAnythingElse causes the dreaded problem where you generally just get an empty string back with `nextLine`. You can invoke a 'blank' nextLine (don't assign it to anything), but then your input processing is broken if the user ever hits that really big, centrally placed key on their keyboard, so that seems like a bad move, even if it is common advice. The real solution is to update the delimiter to `\\R`, but once you've done that, you don't need nextLine to read lines, just next will do it. Using *only* nextLine does work fine, but if that's what you want, just.. make a BufferedReader instead, Scanner is overkill. Conclusion: There are no scenarios where nextLine ever makes sense.

2] If some protocol explicitly says to use `float`, or you know all about IEEE style floating point numbers, you know enough to know when you can ignore this advice. Until you do, heed it.

Answer (score 0):

This code will do the trick:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < numLines ; i++){
    name = scanner.next();
    for(int j = 0 ; j < numNumbers ; j++){
        numbers.add(scanner.nextFloat());
    }
    cities.add(new City(name, numbers));
    numbers.clear();
}
```